# How to create values from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i gotta start by saying that I'm a ultra beginner at python and this is also my first post here, so constructive criticism in very well appreciated. So I got an assignment that i need to take some values from a text file and make a list out of them, but I have no idea how to do this.
The text file is as follow:

```
temperatuur 20.8 10.4
vochtigheid 70 14
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 6 60
temperatuur 21.8 10.9
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 4 40
temperatuur 21.8 10.9
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 21.8 10.9
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 22.0 11.0
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 22.2 11.1
vochtigheid 65 13
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 22.6 11.3
vochtigheid 70 14
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 22.8 11.4
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 4 40
temperatuur 23.0 11.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 4 40
temperatuur 23.0 11.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting ZZW 50
windkracht 3 30
temperatuur 24.0 12.0
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 3 30
temperatuur 25.0 12.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 2 20
temperatuur 26.0 13.0
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 2 20
temperatuur 27.0 13.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 2 20
temperatuur 27.0 13.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 2 20
temperatuur 25.0 12.5
vochtigheid 60 12
windrichting Z 60
windkracht 3 30
temperatuur 21.0 10.5
vochtigheid 75 15
windrichting W 40
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 19.0 9.5
vochtigheid 75 15
windrichting W 40
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 18.0 9.0
vochtigheid 75 15
windrichting W 40
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 18.0 9.0
vochtigheid 75 15
windrichting W 40
windkracht 5 50
temperatuur 17.0 8.5
vochtigheid 80 16
windrichting W 40
windkracht 6 60
temperatuur 16.5 8.25
vochtigheid 80 16
windrichting W 40
windkracht 6 60
temperatuur 14.0 7.0
vochtigheid 80 16
windrichting W 40
windkracht 6 60
temperatuur 10.0 5.0
vochtigheid 80 16
windrichting W 40
windkracht 6 60
```

The text file is called "weerstation.txt".
As you can see it's divided in blocks of 4 with the "labels" being temperatuur (temperature), vochtigheid (humidity), windrichting (wind direction) and windkracht (wind speed). These "labels" repeat 24 time 'cause they are taken every hour for a whole day.
The assignment is to take only the values of the label "temperatuur" (temperature in Dutch) and to make a list out of it and save this list in an separate text file. The first value is the temperature in centigrades and the second one is the associated voltage in mV.

The second assignment is to make a graph that reads the previously created text file (thus the one created in the first assignment) and make a graph out of it. The x-axis being the hours and the y-axis being the temperature values (in centigrades).

I've gotten this far on my own:

```
L=[]
lista = []
listadef = []

with open('weerstation.txt') as f:
        for temperatuur in f:
            L.append(temperatuur)
# I used the next line just to see if it went allright and then left it there in case I need it again
#        print(L)

a = 0
while (a < len(L)):
    lista = L[a]
    listadef.append(lista)
    lista = []
    a = a+4 #I knew that the "temperatuur label" repeats itself after every 4 lines so that's why i took that route 


print(listadef)
```

And that gives me the following:

```
['temperatuur 20.8 10.4\n', 'temperatuur 21.8 10.9\n', 'temperatuur 21.8 10.9\n', 'temperatuur 21.8 10.9\n', 'temperatuur 22.0 11.0\n', 'temperatuur 22.2 11.1\n', 'temperatuur 22.6 11.3\n', 'temperatuur 22.8 11.4\n', 'temperatuur 23.0 11.5\n', 'temperatuur 23.0 11.5\n', 'temperatuur 24.0 12.0\n', 'temperatuur 25.0 12.5\n', 'temperatuur 26.0 13.0\n', 'temperatuur 27.0 13.5\n', 'temperatuur 27.0 13.5\n', 'temperatuur 25.0 12.5\n', 'temperatuur 21.0 10.5\n', 'temperatuur 19.0 9.5\n', 'temperatuur 18.0 9.0\n', 'temperatuur 18.0 9.0\n', 'temperatuur 17.0 8.5\n', 'temperatuur 16.5 8.25\n', 'temperatuur 14.0 7.0\n', 'temperatuur 10.0 5.0\n']
```

As you can see, it ain't much. 
So can anyone help me with this with a clear explanation of what you did, pretty please (:

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Concentrate on creating a *very clear* problem statement. Add only information that is [required to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to read the text file and use the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) module to draw the figure you want. More details can be seen in the following code.

```
import fileinput

temp_values = []
for line in fileinput.input("weerstation.txt"):
    print line, type(line)
    if 'temperatuur' in line:
        temp_values.append(line.strip().split()[1])  # split the list and just add the temperature

with open("temp_values.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(temp_values))                 # save values to temp_values.txt and finish assignment 1

print temp_values
# ['10.4', '10.9', '10.9', '10.9', '11.0', '11.1', '11.3', '11.4', '11.5', '11.5', '12.0', '12.5', '13.0', '13.5', '13.5', '12.5', '10.5', '9.5', '9.0', '9.0', '8.5', '8.25', '7.0', '5.0']


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                     # using matplotlib to draw figure and finish assignment 2

plt.plot([i for i in xrange(0, 24)], temp_values)
plt.xlabel("Hours")
plt.ylabel("Temperatures")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say that in the first assignment I need to make a list out of both values (the degrees and mV values) and save it into a text file.
Then I read that text file to make the graph. I understood now how to take both values and to put them in the text file but how  can you only read the first value to make the graph?

Comment: To read the `temp_values.txt`, you can also use the fileinput.input() function, for each line in your text file, just split the line and keep the first value. The process can be simplified like `values = [ line.split()[1] for line in fileinput.input("temp_values.txt") ]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only lines starting with 'temperatuur':

```
with open('weerstation.txt') as f:
    L = [line for line in f.readlines() if line.startswith('temperatuur')]
```

If you want to split line like 'temperatuur 20.8 10.4\n' to three values use split function (but don't forget value1 and value2 will be strings and you have to convert them to numbers if youw want to create graph):

```
label, value1, value2 = line.split()
```